# Cordova inappbrowser executescript() not working in ios 10

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm developing a Cordova app. In my project, I have used inappbrowser to view the website. Now, I want to make a cross communication from the inappbrowser to my app. I saw about executescript() method in inappbrowser.

This is my code. It is working fine in android device. I can get the value from the site. But in iOS, it is not working. Is there any way around to get this working?????

```
inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url,'_blank','location=yes');
    inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
      inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({
        code: "JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login'))" },
        function(data) {  // callback function
          console.log(data);
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue on iOS?